# Django View that shows related model context

Tags: django, django-models

I'm learning and I'm struggling to create a Django view that displays a Company Detail model, but also can show the associated location names that are located in child FK models to the Company.

What I've tried includes these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    street = models.CharField('Street', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    province = models.CharField('Province/State', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField('Postal/Zip Code', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company_comments = models.TextField('Comments', max_length=350, null=True, blank=True)

class Region(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name

class District(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    dictrict_ops_leadership = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district_name

My view looks like:

class CompanyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'main/company_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['region'] = Region.objects.all()
        context['district'] = District.objects.all()
        return context

I want to call **all instances of Region and District** for the **single instance of Company.** 

With my HTML tags as :    <p>{{ region }}{{ district }}</p>

It just returns a list of query's of all Region and District instances:

    <QuerySet [<Region: RegionA>, <Region: RegionB>]>
    <QuerySet [<District: DistrictA>, <District: DistrictB>]>

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks
```

Comment: Instead of `context['region'] = Region.objects.all()` try `context['region'] = self.region_set.all()` and then district as `context['district'] = District.objects.filter(id__in=context['region'].values_list('id', flat=True))`

Comment: Thank you, I believe I need to define region_set in your example. With your example I get 'CompanyDetailView' object has no attribute 'region_set'

Answer (score 0):

```
Region.objects.filter(company__company_name = 'Your Company Name')
District.objects.filter(company__company_name = 'Your Company Name')
```

This will give You to the Region and District they related to the Your Comapany Name

Comment: to make it more dynamic you can query the related objects pointing to `self.get_object()`